# How to find which process is regularly writing to disk?

Tags: linux, debian, logs, hard-disk

How can I find which process is constantly writing to disk?

I like my workstation to be close to silent and I just build a new system (P8B75-M + Core i5 3450s -- the 's' because it has a lower max TDP) with quiet fans etc. and installed Debian Wheezy 64-bit on it.

And something is getting on my nerve: I can hear some kind of pattern like if the hard disk was writing or seeking someting (*tick...tick...tick...trrrrrr* rinse and repeat every second or so).

In the past I had a similar issue in the past (many, many years ago) and it turned out it was some CUPS log or something and I simply redirected that one (not important) logging to a (real) RAM disk.

But here I'm not sure.

I tried the following:

```
ls -lR /var/log > /tmp/a.tmp && sleep 5 && ls -lR /var/log > /tmp/b.tmp && diff /tmp/?.tmp
```

but nothing is changing there.

Now the strange thing is that I also hear the pattern when the prompt asking me to enter my LVM decryption passphrase is showing.

Could it be something in the kernel/system I just installed or do I have a faulty harddisk?

`hdparm -tT /dev/sda` report a correct HD speed (130 GB/s non-cached, sata 6GB) and I've already installed and compiled from big sources (Emacs) without issue so I don't think the system is bad.

(HD is a Seagate Barracude 500GB)

Comment: Are you sure it's a hard drive making that noise, and not something else? (Check the fans, including PSU fan. Had very strange clicking noises once when a very thin cable was too close to a fan and would sometimes very slightly touch the blades and bounce for a few "clicks"...)

Comment: @Mat: I'll take the hard drive outside of the case (the connectors should be long enough) to be sure and I'll report back ; )

Comment: Make sure your disk filesystems are mounted relatime or noatime. File reads can be causing writes to inodes to record the access time.

Answer (score 66):

Did you tried to examin what programs like [`iotop`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/linux-iotop-simple-top-like-io-monitor/attachment/iotop-output-screenshot/) is showing? It will tell you exacly what kind of process is currently writing to the disk.

example output:

```
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    7 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
    8 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
 1033 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [flush-8:0]
   10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
```

Comment: thanks for that tip.  I didn't know about *iotop*.  On Debian I did an *apt-cache search iotop* to find out that I had to *apt-get iotop*.  Very cool command!

Comment: I use `iotop -o -b -d 10` which every 10secs prints  a list of processes that read/wrote to disk and the amount of IO bandwidth used.

Comment: Unfortunately on new systems it mostly just shows `jbd2` as everything goes via the journal

Answer (score 20):

You can enable IO debugging via `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump` and then watch the debugging messages in */var/log/syslog*. This has the advantage of obtaining some type of log file with past activities whereas `iotop` only shows the current activity.

Comment: It is absolutely crazy to leave sysloging enabled when block_dump is active. Logging causes disk activity, which causes logging, which causes disk activity etc. Better stop syslog before enabling this (and use dmesg to read the messages)

Comment: You are absolutely right, although the effect isn't as dramatic as you describe it. If you just want to have a short peek at the disk activity there is no need to stop the syslog daemon.

Comment: I've tried it about 2 years ago and it brought my machine to a halt. One of these days when I have nothing important running I'll try it again :)

Comment: I tried it, nothing really happened. Especially because of file system buffering. A write to syslog doesn't immediately trigger a write to disk.

Comment: I would assume there is rate general rate limiting in place for the log messages, which handles this case too(?)

Comment: I have a ZFS pool and the kernel log is on the system SSD, so no recursive activity. But for some activites I cannot see the process: `Jun  1 07:43:13 nas kernel: [44479.254095] z_wr_iss(769): WRITE block 9663902944 on sda1 (8 sectors)` What does `z_wr_iss` mean? My disk got waked up by those write.

Comment: @Lion This belongs to a new question. Anyway, `z_wr_iss` is a kernel thread for the ZFS file system. Further details are not known to me.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the disk noises are due to a process causing a write and not to [some disk spindown problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44103/how-to-find-which-process-is-regularly-writing-to-disk/44110#44110), you can use the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) (install the [`auditd` package](https://packages.debian.org/auditd)). Put a watch on the `sync` calls and its friends:

```
auditctl -S sync -S fsync -S fdatasync -a exit,always
```

Watch the logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. Be careful not to do this if the audit logs themselves are flushed! Check in `/etc/auditd.conf` that the `flush` option is set to `none`.

If files are being flushed often, a likely culprit is the system logs. For example, if you log failed incoming connection attempts and someone is probing your machine, that will generate a lot of entries; this can cause a disk to emit machine gun-style noises. With the basic log daemon sysklogd, check `/etc/syslog.conf`: if a log file name is not be preceded by `-`, then that log is flushed to disk after each write.

Comment: @StephenKitt Huh. No. The asker mentioned Debian so I've changed it to a link to the Debian package.

Answer (score 7):

### fatrace (File Activity Trace)

[fatrace](https://github.com/martinpitt/fatrace) reports file access events (Open, Read, Write, Close) from **all** running processes.

> Its main purpose is to find processes which keep waking up the disk unnecessarily and thus prevent some power saving.

When running it outputs in real time one line per file event in this format:

```
<timestamp> <process-name(pid)>: <file-event> </path/to/file>
```

For example:

```
23:10:21.375341 Plex Media Serv(2290): W /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-UID/Plex/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Logs/Plex Media Server.log
```

#### From which you easily get all the necessary infos

- **WHEN:** Timestamp, if using the `--timestamp` option
- **WHO:** Process name (who is causing the activity)
- **WHAT:** File operation event (O-pen, R-read, W-rite, C-lose)
- **WHERE:** Filepath (where is it writing to).
- **SCOPE** You can limit the search scope with `--current-mount` to only record events on the partition/mount of your current directory.

  - So simply `cd` into the volume which corresponds to your spinning HDD first, and there run `ftrace` with the `--current-mount` option.
  - Without this option, all  (real)  partitions/mount points are being watched.

### Super practical

- In comparison to all the other answers (as of 2022-07-16) with this tool you can very quickly and efficiently find out **which process so far unknown to you** is causing **what file activity so far unknown to you**.
- All the other tools were not useful for my purposes because they either let you monitor a particular process or a particular directory/file. But not let you "investigate the unknown" in a quick and real time manner.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, great tool!

Comment: Glad that it helped you! I hope that over time `fatrace` will get more popular for its investigative strengths that I tried to outlay in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can wack on this a bit. Should narrow it down for most.

```
find / -mount -newer /proc -print
```

Give files modified since boot on the physical device of the / files system.  Knowing the files will likely help identify the writer.

Comment: A variant of this that worked best for me was: `rm -f a; touch a; sleep 30; find / -mount -newer a -print |less`

Answer (score 5):

It might be your drives automatically spinning down, lots of consumer-grade drives do that these days.  Unfortunately on even a lightly loaded system, this results in the drives constantly spinning down and then spinning up again, especially if you're running hddtemp or similar to monitor the drive temperature (most drives stupidly don't let you query the SMART temperature value without spinning up the drive - cretinous!).

This is not only annoying, it can wear out the drives faster as many drives have only a limited number of park cycles. e.g. see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/952556 for a description of the problem.

I disable idle-spindown on all my drives with the following bit of shell code.  you could put it in an /etc/rc.boot script, or in /etc/rc.local or similar.

```
for disk in /dev/sd? ; do
  /sbin/hdparm -q -S 0 "$disk"
done
```

Comment: that you can't query SMART readings without spinning up the drive leaves me speechless :-/  Now obviously the "spinning down" issue can become quite complicated.  Regarding disabling the spinning down: wouldn't that in itself cause the HD to wear out faster?  I mean: it's never ever "resting" as long as the system is on then?

Comment: IIRC you can query some SMART values without causing the drive to spin up, but temperature isn't one of them on any of the drives i've tested (incl models from WD, Seagate, Samsung, Hitachi).  Which is, of course, crazy because concern over temperature is one of the reasons for idling a drive.   re: wear: AIUI 1. constant velocity is less wearing than changing speed. 2. the drives have to park the heads in a safe area and a drive is only rated to do that so many times (IIRC up to a few hundred thousand - easily exceeded if the drive is idling and spinning up every few seconds)

Comment: It's a long debate regarding whether it's better to leave drives running or to spin them down. Personally I believe it's best to leave them running - I turn my computer off at night and when I go out but other than that I never spin my drives down. Some people prefer to spin them down, say, at night if they're leaving the computer on or if the computer's idle for a long time, and in such cases the advantage of spinning them down for a few hours versus leaving them running is debatable. What's never good though is when the hard drive repeatedly spins down and up again in a short period of time.

Comment: Note also that spinning the drive down *after* it's been idle for a few hours is a bit silly, because if it's been idle for a few hours then it's likely to be used again within an hour. In that case, it would seem better to spin the drive down promptly if it's idle (like, within 10 minutes), but it's also possible for the drive to be idle for a few minutes when someone is using the computer and is likely to need the drive again soon.

Comment: I thought sure this would fix my issue as I hear the drive make a periodic clacking sound (3-4 times/second) like it's writing even when it's not mounted!  But I still hear the noise after running this command.  Worryingly, it's the drive I use to back up my internal SSD...

Comment: @Michael Unless it's been making that same sound since the day you bought it, I'd replace that drive immediately.  It almost certainly indicates that the drive is about to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that s.m.a.r.t was causing an external USB disk to spin up again and again on my raspberry pi. Although SMART is generally a good thing, I decided to disable it again and since then it seems that unwanted disk activity has stopped

Comment: You can configure smart daemon not to scan USB disks, most good linux distributions do this by default.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to narrow it down to an exact disk use the following:

run `lsblk` and look up the device number. In the case below it is `9:126`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md126       9:126  0  13.8T  0 raid0 /mnt/InternalPhase
sdb           8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md126       9:126  0  13.8T  0 raid0 /mnt/InternalPhase
sdc           8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdc1        8:33   0   7.3T  0 part  /mnt/InternalFBE
```

run `lsof | grep '9,126'` with the `:` replace with `,` compared to the above disk  number. In my case this shows up as:

```
bash      389162            root  cwd       DIR              9,126      4096  449183796 /mnt/InternalPhase/0000000001/CHANNEL01/LIVE/PHASE/DATA/2018/10/04
```

with the PID of `389162` kill this process using:

```
kill -9 389162
```

Comment: I guess this tests for the moment the command is run. How do I get it to monitor over a period of time, like, say, 10 seconds?

Comment: I found it: https://jrs-s.net/2019/06/04/continuously-updated-iostat/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the system needs to flush data from the disk buffers to the disk ever 5 seconds or so by default. Thus if the disk does spin down, there will be little option other than to spin back up again when a flush needs to happen. So the problem is not really avoidable other than by disabling spins downs or disk power management features altogether `hdparm -B 255 /dev/hdax`. This is probably the better option since restarting so often can definitely be more damaging than simply staying on all the time.

Comment: It's only going to flush data if there's any data to flush. If the disk is really not in use, then there isn't going to be any buffered data to flush.